# Chekbox MVC not Sending back the data. Using Html.Chekboxfor using proto.io not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

[image]Style which i applied is from hrere : http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

---

```
/**** On off flip switch CSS*/
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
border: 0px solid #999999;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
width: 200%;
margin-left: -100%;
-moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
-webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
-o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner > div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner .onoffswitch-active {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #C2C2C2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner .onoffswitch-inactive {
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #C2C2C2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right;
}


.onoffswitch-switch {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-active .onoffswitch-switch {
    background: #27CA89;
    left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-inactive .onoffswitch-switch {
    background: #F23F3F;
    right: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-active .onoffswitch-switch:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #27CA89 transparent transparent #27CA89;
    border-width: 15px 10px;
}

.onoffswitch-inactive .onoffswitch-switch:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #F23F3F #F23F3F transparent;
    border-width: 15px 10px;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

---

View looks like the following

---

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsLockedOut, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @*@Html.CheckBoxFor( model=> model.IsLockedOut, new {@class="checkbox"})
                      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsLockedOut) *@
            <div class="onoffswitch">
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsLockedOut, new { @class = "onoffswitch-checkbox" })
                @*<input type="checkbox" name="IsLockedOut" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="IsLockedOut" data-val="true"  value="true" @Html.Raw(Model.IsLockedOut ? "checked=\"checked\"": "") >*@
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="IsLockedOut">
                    <div class="onoffswitch-inner">
                        <div class="onoffswitch-inactive">
                            <div class="onoffswitch-switch"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="onoffswitch-active">
                            <div class="onoffswitch-switch"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
```

The button dosn't seem to work.

I can use the **Input type as checkbox.**

but when the checkbox is not selected then the value is not comming back in the request object. It makes life difficult.

### here is how the controller looks.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(string UserName, FormCollection formCollection, string[] selectedRoles)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var userToUpdate = db.ApplicationUser.Where(u => u.Username == UserName).Include(u=> u.Roles).SingleOrDefault();


            if (TryUpdateModel(userToUpdate, "", new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "IsLockedOut" }))
            {
                try
                {

                    UpdateRolesForUser(selectedRoles, userToUpdate);
                    db.Entry(userToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Todo Put a log message.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Oops... Some thing went wrong." + ex.Message);
                }


            }

            PopulateAssignedRolesData(userToUpdate);
            return View(userToUpdate);
        }
```

---

Any idea on how to get the checkbox value back in the postback. forcing the form to post the checkbox value down.

The model which i am trying to work out is.

```
public class ApplicationUser
    {

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public  String Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public  String Email { get; set; }

        public  String FirstName { get; set; }
        public  String LastName { get; set; }

        public  DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public  DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public  DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public  DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public  Boolean IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public  string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; set; }


    }

 public class ApplicationUserRole
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Hope more detail helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a model in your view, why don't you put in the argument of your controller that model?

link this

```
public ActionResult Edit(yourmodel model){ [...]
```

Comment: Adding my page screenshot.

Comment: Model wont work, as i have related data which i have to update just following the tutorial for http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application